# Linux bash sorting in reverse order based on a column isn't working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I'm trying to sort a text file in the descending order based on the last column. It just doesn't seem to work.

```
cat 1.txt | sort -r -n -k 4,4

ACHG,89.46,0.08,34200
UUKJL,0.85,-15.00,200
NIMJKY,34.35,0.09,17700
TBBNHW,10.24,0.00,4600
JJkLEYE,73.67,0.48,25400
```

I've tried removing spaces just in case but, hasn't helped. Also, tried sorting by the other fields just to see but, ahve the same problem.

I just can't work out what is wrong with the command I've issued. Please could I request help with this one?

Comment: `sort -t, -rnk 4,4 1.txt` should work

Comment: ah damn thing.. just couldn't think of the field separator... Assumed the default is comma. Thanks a million. I would've gone on & on trying different things except for the field separator.

Comment: Post it as the answer & I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is almost right but it is missing field separator option `-t` that should set comma as field separator.

This should work for you:

```
sort -t, -rnk 4,4 1.txt
```

```
ACHG,89.46,0.08,34200
JJkLEYE,73.67,0.48,25400
NIMJKY,34.35,0.09,17700
TBBNHW,10.24,0.00,4600
UUKJL,0.85,-15.00,200
```

Note that there is no need to use `cat | sort` here.